# Count, orderby and group in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Given a set

Paris
New York
London
New York
Paris
Paris

I'm trying to do a LINQ query that will return a grouping of the Paris, New York, and London **with their respective counts**.

I've been able to do a GroupBy that returns a group containing only the Paris/New York/London in each Grouping.

Sounds relatively simple, but I can't get it to work?

**Edit**:
It's not a homework problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CODE**

```
String[] input = new [] { "Paris", "New York", "London",
                          "New York", "Paris", "Paris" };

var groups = input
    .GroupBy(city => city)
    .Select(group => new { City = group.Key, Count = group.Count() });

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} occurs {1} time(s).", group.City, group.Count);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Paris occurs 3 time(s).
New York occurs 2 time(s).
London occurs 1 time(s).
```

Comment: I didn't give full answer because it sounded like a homework question. Also you can shorten it by using a different overload of the GroupBy method.

Answer (score 0):

Use .Count() on the groupings.